# Button in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to bring the buttons in one row. And I don't want a navbar so how do I make changes to keep the buttons in the same row? I have shared a screenshot of the page that I have to position the buttons [image: This is the OUTPUT]

Below is the piece of code of my work:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?= base_url() ?>admin_voting/create">Add Vote</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn btn-success" href="<?= base_url() ?>admin_voting">Vote lists</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn btn-info" href="<?= base_url() ?>voting">Show Votes</a></li>
</ul>           
        </div>
       </div>
```

Also I am getting some bulletin like dots next to the buttons.How do I remove that?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Your list is missing `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags. I also added the Bootstrap tag to your question as it appears you're using it.

Comment: you want the buttons in a row within `col-sm-3`?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you could use the following:

```
ul, ol {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

The inline causes the `ul`'s or `ol`'s to be next to eachother.
The none under list-style-type makes the dots disappear.

Also: use `ul` or `ol` tags inside of your `li` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Add css class below to remove the dots:

```
.sidebar li{
    display: inline-block
}
```

also, fix the list style with:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please check the Bootstrap documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#unstyled